# Turn off outlining for getters and setters

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When expanding collapsed properties - I want the getters and setters to be expanded as well.

When editing **html**, we have the option to set outlining rules by tags. I couldn't find the same thing for **C#** (so I can turn off outlining for property getters and setters). Does it exist?

Comment: I don't think there is anything in VS's GUI to do it, but the API may be exposed to change the behavior in [EnvDTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.aspx)